# using any() in python is returning the array as a nonetype

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

So I'm trying to get the average of white points from an Opencv mask, but I had the issue of "ValueError: the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. use a.any() or a.all."
so I looking into how to use those, and I'm pretty sure I understand it, but I'm getting returns of none-type from the any(points)

```
points = cv2.findNonZero(mask)
if any(points) != None:
    avg = np.mean(points, axis=0)
```

basically why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

(also side note I need the "if points != None:", because else-wise np.mean() throws a fit since I'm using a video feed that doesn't always pick something up on the mask)

Also, this is a separate question but I suspect once I get this working the np.mean() will pick up the none in the points array anyway (if that works how I think it does), and fail. how would I have it specifically select the non None points?

(last note, my first post on stacks, so sorry if the question is a bit messy.)

Comment: 1. Use `points.any()` instead of `any(points)` 2. `points.any()` returns `True` or `False` -- neither of these will be equal to `None` so you'll always fall through to the next line.

Comment: `I'm pretty sure I understand it [...] why is this happening, and how can I fix it?` somehow there appears to be an error in your question's logic :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing your `ValueError` is - as erip hinted at - that python's `any` expects a sequence of booleans, and your numpy array (being at least 2d) is not that.

`any` will try to iterate over the first dimension of the array and instead of finding a single `True` or `False` it will find a tuple `(x,y)`. It doesn't know what to do with that, hence you get the ValueError.

If all you need/want is to make sure that there are some points to average you can use:

```py
points = cv2.findNonZero(mask)
if len(points) > 0:
    avg = np.mean(points, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [870]: x==0
Out[870]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
In [871]: if x==0:print('yes')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-871-61335cb0afd3>", line 1, in <module>
    if x==0:print('yes')
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This is the way the error means for you to use `any`:

```
In [872]: if (x==0).any():print('yes')
yes
```

With a multidimensional array, `any` and `all` can reduce one axis, though that still leaves you with a multi-element boolean array

```
In [875]: (x==0).any(axis=1)
Out[875]: array([ True,  True, False])
In [876]: (x==0).any(axis=0)
Out[876]: array([ True, False,  True])
```